# Creating a list with input, however nothing shows up after compiling

Tags: java, list

I wish to create a list, and the list has a input as length, however after I put in the preferable length as input, the list won't show up;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JJ {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      JJ.getalist();
   }
      public static ArrayList<Integer> getalist(){
          ArrayList<Integer> JJ = new ArrayList<Integer>();
          System.out.println("Oh, How long would you want your list to be?");
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
          int length = in.nextInt();
          for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
               int point = (int) (Math.random()*9);
               JJ.add(new Integer(point));
          }
        return  JJ;
      }   
}
```

Comment: You aren't printing it to the console; where are you expecting it to "show up"?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use `System.out.println()` in the main method when invoking `JJ.getalist()`. You can pass `JJ.getalist()` return value as the argument of the method printing to the console like this:
`System.out.println(JJ.getalist())`.